# Reducing a function using dictionary

Tags: python, if-statement

I have two functions that are very similar:

```
def hier_group(self):
    if self.sku:
        return {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}", "id": "$id", "ix": "$ix"}
    else:
        return {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}", "ix": "$ix"}

def hier_group_merge(self):
     if self.sku:
         return {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}", "id": "$id"}
     else:
         return {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}"}
```

I am trying to reduce into 1 function that has only one if/else.

The only difference in both functions is `"ix": "$ix"`.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
def hier_group(self, ix=True):
       if self.sku:
           return {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}", "id": "$id" f'{',"ix": "$ix"' if ix == True else ""}'}
       else:
           return {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}"  f'{',"ix": "$ix"' if ix == True else ""}'}
```

But it's getting trick to return `, "ix": "$ix"`.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: The dollar signs represents a parameter on mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a base dictionary, then add keys as appropriate.

```
def hier_group(self, ix=True):
    d = { f'{self.hierarchic}': f'${self.hierarchic}' }
    if self.sku:
        d['id'] = '$id'
    if ix:
        d['ix'] = '$ix'
    return d
```

However, there are many who believe using two functions, rather than having one function behave like two different functions based on a Boolean argument, is preferable.

```
def hier_group(self):
    d = { f'{self.hierarchic}': f'${self.hierarchic}' }
    if self.sku:
        d['id'] = '$id'
    return d

def hier_group_with_ix(self):
    d = self.hier_group()
    d.update('ix': '$ix')
    return d
```

You might also use a private method that takes an arbitrary list of attribute names.

```
# No longer needs self, so make it a static method
@staticmethod
def _build_group(attributes):
    return {f'{x}: f'${x} for x in attributes}


def build_group(self, ix=True):
    attributes = [self.hierarchic]
    if ix:
        attributes.append('ix')
    if self.sku:
        attributes.append('id')
    return self._build_group(attributes)
```

You will probably ask: why is using a Boolean attribute *here* OK? My justification is that you aren't really altering the control flow
of `build_group` with such an argument; you are using it to
build up a list of explicit arguments for the private method. (The `dataclass` decorator in the standard library takes a similar approach: a number of Boolean-valued arguments to indicate whether various methods should be generated automatically.)

Comment: Thank you very @chepner. I really liked your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid repeating common parts:

```
def hier_group(self, ix=True):
    out = {f"{self.hierarchic}": f"${self.hierarchic}"}
    if self.sku:
        out["id"] = "$id"
    if ix:
        out["ix"] = "$ix"
```